# Flask form validation technique

Tags: python, validation, sqlite, flask

This is currently the code that I'm using to validate and check for errors in a flask app, where the form fields are coming from a /registration html page:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['register'] == 'Register':
            if request.form.get("eulacheck") != "on":
                return regError("Please read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and the License Terms.")
            if request.form['username'] == "":
                return regError("Please select a username.")
            if request.form['password1'] == "":
                return regError("Please enter a password.")
            if request.form['password2'] == "":
                return regError("Please confirm password.")
            if request.form['password1'] != request.form['password2']:
                return regError("Passwords did not match. Please enter passwords again.")
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password1']
            hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('UTF-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            id = randint(1000,9999)
            if request.form['email1'] != "":
                if request.form['email2'] == "":
                    return regError("Please confirm email.")
                if request.form['email1'] != request.form['email2']:
                    return regError("Email addresses did not match. Please enter emails again.")
                email = request.form['email1']
                insert_db("INSERT INTO Users (ID, Username, Email, Hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (id, username, email, hash))
                flash("Account registration successfull! Please use your credentials to login below.")
                return render_template("login.html",pageType=['login'],flashType="info")
            insert_db("INSERT INTO Users (ID, Username, Hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (id, username, hash))
            flash("Account registration successfull! Please use your credentials to login below.")
            return render_template("login.html",pageType=['login'],flashType="info")
    return render_template("register.html",pageType=['register'])


def regError(message):
    flash(message)
    return render_template("register.html",pageType=['register'],flashType="danger")
```

This code seems a bit messy and repetitive, is there a better way that I should be doing this? 
  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `register()`, the format is as following:

```
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['register'] == 'Register':
            stuff()
    return render_template("register.html",pageType=['register'])
```

This can easily be condensed using `and`:

```
def register():
    if request.method == "POST" and request.form['register'] == 'Register':
            stuff()
    return render_template("register.html", pageType=['register'])
```

Also, you are not inserting whitespaces between arguments.

```
stuff(3,3)  # <--Unconventional
stuff(3, 3) # <--More conventional
```

Another stylistic issue is some of your lines are too long. For all lines, `line.length <= 79`. You can read about the specific python conventions on the [Python website](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
For making it look less messy and repetitive, look at [this answer to a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323259/4237459). It is about implementing `switch` and `case` statements into Python, which seems perfect for your situation.

Comment: Yup, I can definitely make the first `and` change, and I'll watch out for the whitespaces between arguments. Thanks a lot for the help!